# Initial Condition for Joints

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I would like to know is there is a way to start a simulation with initial angles in a model.

I have tried in a plugin:

```
Link_A->SetAngle(0,InitialAngle);
```

But, when the simulation starts, the model move it's joint dynamically to the InitialAngle. I need a model with an initial condition in the joint's angles.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1469/initial-condition-for-joints/) by [vcparedesc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/183/vcparedesc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use [SetJointPosition](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f38ef6b4017d/gazebo/physics/Model.hh?at=default#cl-201), this may be what you want.  But if there are active controllers, be sure to set new targets at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1